# How impure can an impure subgroup be?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

A subgroup $H$ of an abelian group $G$ is called *pure* if $nH=nG\cap H$ for all $n$. We always have $nH\subset nG\cap H$, so if $H$ is impure then $nH$ is a proper subgroup of $nG\cap H$ for some $n$.

Is  there an abelian group $G$, a subgroup $H$, and an $n$, such that $H\cap nG$ has finite index in $G$, but $nH$ has infinite index?